# django sequence:item 4 expected string or unicode int found

Tags: python, django, models

I'm running python manage.py migrate with my models,the database was already made i'm just making the models for it now,
 but getting this error when running the command

```
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    sequence item 4: expected string or Unicode, int found
```

my models

```
class Publisher(models.Model):
    publisherCode = models.CharField(3,primary_key=True)
    publisherName = models.CharField(25)
    city = models.CharField(20)

class Book(models.Model):
    bookCode = models.CharField(4,primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(40)
    publisherCode = models.ForeignKey(Publisher)
    type = models.CharField(3)
    paperback = models.CharField(1)

class Branch(models.Model):
    branchNum = models.DecimalField(2,0,primary_key=True)
    branchName = models.CharField(50)
    branchLocation = models.CharField(50)

class Copy(models.Model):
    bookCode = models.ForeignKey(Book)
    branchNum = models.ForeignKey(Branch)
    copyNum = models.DecimalField(2,0,primary_key=True)
    quality = models.CharField(20)
    price = models.DecimalField(8,2)
```

Comment: What if you write the `CharField(..)`s with `CharField(max_length=...)` instead? Based on the source code, it is not an explicit (!) parameter of `__init__` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/_modules/django/db/models/fields/#CharField

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Short answer:** make from `max_length` an *explicitly named* argument.

Based on the [source code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/_modules/django/db/models/fields/#CharField), `max_length` is *not* an explicit parameter of `CharField`, it thus performs a call to the `__init__` of [`Field`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/_modules/django/db/models/fields/#Field), and this has as arguments:

> ```
> def __init__(self, verbose_name=None, name=None, primary_key=False,
>              max_length=None, unique=False, blank=False, null=False,
>              db_index=False, rel=None, default=NOT_PROVIDED, editable=True,
>              serialize=True, unique_for_date=None, unique_for_month=None,
>              unique_for_year=None, choices=None, help_text='', db_column=None,
>              db_tablespace=None, auto_created=False, validators=(),
>              error_messages=None):
> ```

So as you can see, your first unnamed parameter, actually will match with `verbose_name`, and this should be a string. Of course providing the number as a string will *not* solve the problem since then you pass the `max_length` to the `verbose_name`, instead, and furthermore `max_length` is, as far as I know a required parameter for `CharField`.

The solution is to explicitly use `max_length` such that it is clear that you want to assign `4` to that parameter. The same holds for the `DecimalField` by the way:

```
class Publisher(models.Model):
    publisherCode = models.CharField(max_length=3,primary_key=True)
    publisherName = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Book(models.Model):
    bookCode = models.CharField(max_length=4,primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    publisherCode = models.ForeignKey(Publisher)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    paperback = models.CharField(max_length=1)

class Branch(models.Model):
    branchNum = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=0, primary_key=True)
    branchName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    branchLocation = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Copy(models.Model):
    bookCode = models.ForeignKey(Book)
    branchNum = models.ForeignKey(Branch)
    copyNum = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=0, primary_key=True)
    quality = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
```

This is more "*self-explaining*" as well: a user with not much Django experience, can usually guess that `max_length=3` means that the string can contain at most three characters, whereas without explicit naming, he/she should have to look up what exactly this parameter means.

I find it rather weird that you use a `DecimalField` with `decimal_places=0`, since this is basically an `IntegerField`, usually it is better to use an `IntegerField` in that case since it maps more directly to what it is conceptually, the database can store it in a more compact way, and arithmetic operations are usually correct in integer land, whereas in floating point land, there can be rounding errors.

Comment: oh wow very throughout, yea that decimal part wasn't done by me :p